# PageSpeedInsights Result URL

Tags: pagespeed-insights

How to store the resulting URL? For example, yes I ram the test using PageSpeedInsights browser application and today I hit the resultant URL in a browser instead of showing result it is getting reloaded again? Is there any possibility of storing the result and viewing it later sometime...